# Drawing a circular image on top of another image - UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I've been struggling with this method for a while. I am drawing an avatar on top of another image. The user picture I want to be a circle, however I can't seem to figure out how. The user picture is a `UIImage` and not a `UIImageView`. I am aware of how to make a circle if it is an imageview. Below is the code. There might be a better approach.

```
-(UIImage *)drawImage:(UIImage*)pinImage withBadge:(UIImage *)user{



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pinImage.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [pinImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pinImage.size.width, pinImage.size.height)];
    [user drawInRect:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, user.size.width/2, user.size.height/2)];
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultImage;

}
```

The result is good, but the user image is still square, it is not circle. I have tried making the add the User image to a `UIImageView`, transform it to a circle, and then use it in the method by calling `yourImageView.image`, but no luck. I also tried numerous other ways. My logic is more than likely incorrect.

The desired outcome is a rounded image place on top of a pin/annotation. Where the black dot would be an image (a bigger circle than this).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clip the image context to the path of an image

```
// Start the image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pinImage.size, NO, 0.0);
UIImage *resultImage = nil;

// Get the graphics context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Draw the first image
[pinImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pinImage.size.width, pinImage.size.height)];

// Get the frame of the second image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, user.size.width/2, user.size.height/2)

// Add the path of an ellipse to the context
// If the rect is a square the shape will be a circle
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
// Clip the context to that path
CGContextClip(context);

// Do the second image which will be clipped to that circle
[user drawInRect:rect];

// Get the result
UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 

// End the image context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This doesnt give the desired effect. The black dot in the image above I was to be a profile picture. But my `user` image is currently a square/rect so it is not round when placed on the `pinImage`.

Comment: I tried this `CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, user.size.width *2, user.size.height*2));` , I dont quite understand this part.

Comment: @Gman Well, no wonder since I didn't really think it through! ;)

Comment: @Gman I have updated my answer to draw the first image and the clip to the circle where the second image is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Create a circular path and then clip to that?

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx, ....);
CGContextClip(ctx);
```